# Detecting edge in the "hard" way

Tags: java

I am constraint to use getNeighbours to make a list of edges.

So instead of

```
for (i = 0; i < verticies.length;i++){
   for (j = 0; j < vertices.length; j++){
        for (verticies.isedge(i,j){
            addedge(i,j);
} } }
```

I have to use the getneighbour(vertex ver1) method which will return an array of objects[] that is connected to ver1 and array of int that signify the weight of each edge. The straight away thought is, "ok i'll simply run getbeighbours on all the vertices and filter out all the duplicates". Sure but I don't know how to do the "filter out all the duplicates"

Note: I cannot use the first method. It is not allowed, I "need" to use getNeighbour to complete this problem because of big-oh limitation.

Comment: if you initialize `j` to `i+1` I believe it would achieve what you want, also change that 3rd `for` to an `if`.

Comment: I cannot use the first method. It is not allowed, I "need" to use getNeighbour to complete this problem because of big-oh limitation.

Comment: I don't follow. The approach I mentioned yields all combinations of 2 vertices, which you can then pass to your `isedge` function, why is that not allowed? What do you mean by 'big-oh limitation'? It seems silly to first calculate all permutations only to filter out duplicates when you can yield all combinations directly with what I mentioned (`j = i+1`).

Comment: I already get the first method to work, but i am required to use getNeighbours to complete this part. So that's why i'm so confuse and fustrated.